# GCM implement an application in taxi

Tags: java, android, sockets, websocket, google-cloud-messaging

I am implementing an application type taxi.
This application uses GCM to alert the driver if someone is asking taxi and the customer if the taxi has arrived.
The problem I have is that the GCM is a late arrival to the devices.
One possible solution would be to implement socket, however, this could cause problems with the battery.
Another possible solution would be to implement an XMPP server.

what recommendation would be the best, or is there a better solution to these.

Answer (score 1):

Despite being late arrival of GCM notification, you have to use it along with XMPP. Because when your application is in background or User crashes the application you have to send GCM notification to user.